# What can be the consequences of having more then 1000 code modules in Access accdb?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2016

From MS Access specifications:

> Number of modules (including forms and reports that have the HasModule property set to True) < 1000

In our accdb we have > 1300 code modules, but It works OK for years.

What can go wrong with this deviation from specs?

Comment: Please don't ask double-barreled questions. Are you interested in errors that might occur when exceeding the maximum amount of code modules, or are you interested in reducing the amount of code modules in a single database? Please ask about _one_ of these.

Comment: Closely tight Qs. There should be a reason why MS specified this limitation, so please if someone knows about it. Then probebly we will have to reduce wisely the No of code modules so the answarrer might have expirience with that and contribute too, thanks

Comment: I disagree. Answering why this is a problem certainly doesn't answer how to avoid it. Answering how to reduce the number of modules doesn't answer why it's a problem. While you may just want to avoid a problem, others might only be interested in reducing the number of modules to increase maintainability of the database. I can answer how to reduce the number of modules, but won't go speculating about errors that may or may not occur when you exceed the maximum number of modules.

Comment: Well, if it is a minor problem - like it seems to be - then it may not be worth the effort to fix it. So, I will wait to see if someone knows about the 1st part. Removing the 2nd fix part of the Q.

Answer (score 0):

> What can go wrong with this deviation from specs?

An error message like: "Cannot open more code modules", or simply a crash.

It could also be, that MS will not support applications with too many modules. If so, the limit is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in the question, we did about 300 times open new code modules with no error masages nor crashes,,, Regarding MS support, I will be glade to hear where can I get that, because this question shouldn't be here at all, if I knew where to get MS "support"

Comment: Then delete the question.

Comment: ??, I have problems with Addin, and I thought maybe related to that

Comment: 2. There may be some subtle issues with having >1000 CM, affecting  performance, stability, sudden stop etc.

Comment: Indeed. You may try running Access 64-bit and see if the issue persists.